Determine the position of the last line of a page
I need to transfer the creation of a PDF from the React front-end (jsPdf) to a Java back-end. I would like to approach the implementation similar to the frontend with static methods for the respective chapters, headings, images, etc.. For this approach, I need the position of the last line of the previous content of the current page before inserting the new content.
In the front-end, I have implemented this with an object in which I have recorded and manually managed this and other type setting information.
Is it possible to get the vertical position of the previous content in PDFBox? It would also be helpful to define the page layout (e.g. margin, ...) at document level so that every new page has these properties by default.
Extract of the pdfOptions with jsPdf
const pdfOptions: PdfOptions = {
    currentX: 10,
    currentY: 30,
    newPageY: 15,
    doubleSpacing: 10,
    onehalfspacing: 7.5,
    subSectionSpacing: 6,
    singlespacing: 5,
    endOfPageTextTreshold: doc.internal.pageSize.height - 40,
    endOfPageImageTreshold: doc.internal.pageSize.height - 20,
    pageWidth: doc.internal.pageSize.width,
    leftMargin: 10, // used in imageTargetSize
    rightMargin: 10, // used in imageTargetSize
    imageTargetSize: doc.internal.pageSize.width * 0.8 - (10 + 10),
    imagePixelWidth: 640,
    imagePixelHeight: 480,
    fontSizes: {
      title: 16,
      subTitle: 12,
      normalSize: 10,
      small: 9,
      footNoteSize: 8,
    },
  };


"Is it possible to get the vertical position of the previous content in PDFBox?" - Is there nothing below the previous content yet? E.g. a footer, background graphics, margin materials, ...

@mkl
I have now found an approach. I drag the PdfOptions object through the document and always update the vertical position after completing the added content.

I also think that's a sensible approach. If you have to determine the last position some content was added whenever you add new content, you burn a lot of resources. It's better to hold such state information in some PdfOptions object you forward along with the document. You could even add the document itself to the PdfOptions and would only need that single parameter.

@mkl
Thank you for this thought. I had quite a few teething problems with the package. I will take that into consideration. Currently I'm getting various layout parameters from the PdfOptions object and setting the vertical position after a new content. I'll have to think through the approach of dragging the whole document into an object again.

It's not necessary to do that afterwards. It merely would have been easier if you had started with that approach.

@mkl
Ok. Then I misunderstood and didn't comment correctly. I already have a PdfOptions object in which I usually keep final values and also synchronise the vertical position with the document.
